# Error installing Nokogiri when using "bundle install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

When I run `bundle install` it stops with:

```
Installing nokogiri (1.4.3.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I tried installing it manually using "[Installing Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)" but this did work out in my favour.

Do I need to change something?

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb'   
extconf.rb:10: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.  
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes  
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes  
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes  
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes  
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... yes  
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in -lexslt... yes  
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes  
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes  
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes  
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes  
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes  
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes  
creating Makefile
```

Or this:

```
make  
compiling xml_dtd.c  
compiling xml_entity_reference.c  
compiling xml_sax_parser_context.c  
compiling xml_attribute_decl.c  
compiling xml_schema.c  
compiling xml_processing_instruction.c  
compiling xml_cdata.c  
compiling xml_xpath_context.c  
xml_xpath_context.c: In function ‘xpath_generic_exception_handler’:  
xml_xpath_context.c:154:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-     Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors  
make: *** [xml_xpath_context.o] Error 1  

Gem files will remain installed in /home/virinchy/.bundler/tmp/10048/gems/nokogiri-  1.4.3.1 for inspection.  
Results logged to /home/virinchy/.bundler/tmp/10048/gems/nokogiri- 1.4.3.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing nokogiri (1.4.3.1), and Bundler cannot continue.  
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.4.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Installing nokogiri when run bundle install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135596/error-installing-nokogiri-when-run-bundle-install)

Comment: Not a duplicate by chance either... is there a reason you didn't just revise your original question?

Comment: well,but neither of them had an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, Nokogiri 1.4.3.1 is almost three years old. You should upgrade.

Second, please see https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/680 for details around how Debian hardened the gcc compiler. You will need to use either an older version of debian or a newer version of Nokogiri.